# Apache Http Client 4.0.1 SSL Proxy

Tags: java, apache, ssl, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Apache Http client 4.0.1 for communicating with the server. I already have a secure/non secure client code that works just fine.

Recently the new addition being to add proxy to this code, so i added the following piece of code to do that (currently non secure proxy),

```
 HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("localhost", 5555);
 httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
```

This has worked fine with a non secure request. However i am having trouble with a secure (https) request with the same code.

Get the below exception (it tries a few time before failing),

```
Mar 12, 2014 11:14:27 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when connecting to the target host: The target server failed to respond
Mar 12, 2014 11:14:27 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:62)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.createTunnelToTarget(DefaultRequestDirector.java:899)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.establishRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:818)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:644)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    at com.poc.test.SSLTest.main(SSLTest.java:88)
```

Tried following things,

1. For https requests, i added both "http" as well as "https" to the schema registry, using the same SSLFactory as the one used for "https".
2. Changed the proxy to,
   HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("localhost", 5555, "https");

However in both cases it failed with,

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:397)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:572)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    at com.poc.test.SSLTest.main(SSLTest.java:89)
```

Note - I am running a non secure proxy on my localhost via tcpmon.

**EDIT**: Here is the code i am using for the SSL with proxy communication,

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

try {
    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.1");
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = getTrustManagers("jks", new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\SSLKeyStore.ks")), "changeit");
    ctx.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://localhost:8844/Channels/HTTP/getData");
    System.out.println("executing request" + httpget.getRequestLine());

    SSLSocketFactory factory = new SSLSocketFactory(ctx);
    factory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

    ClientConnectionManager manager = httpClient.getConnectionManager();
    manager.getSchemeRegistry().register(new Scheme("https", 443, factory));
    manager.getSchemeRegistry().register(new Scheme("http", 80, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));

    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("localhost", 5555, "http");
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    if (entity != null) {
        System.out.println("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
    }
    EntityUtils.consume(entity);
} catch (Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

Any ideas of what is happening, what am i missing with respect to https and proxy.

**Latest EDIT** - Even tried their example code (ClientExecuteProxy.java) as is, that too failed with proxy. Is this functionality broken?

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 8080, "http");

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);

        HttpHost target = new HttpHost("issues.apache.org", 443, "https");
        HttpGet req = new HttpGet("/");

        System.out.println("executing request to " + target + " via " + proxy);
        HttpResponse rsp = httpclient.execute(target, req);
        HttpEntity entity = rsp.getEntity();

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(rsp.getStatusLine());
        Header[] headers = rsp.getAllHeaders();
        for (int i = 0; i<headers.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(headers[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

        if (entity != null) {
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        }

    } finally {
        // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
        // shut down the connection manager to ensure
        // immediate deallocation of all system resources
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Vicky

Comment: Folks, nobody used/worked on this? I'll post this on the Apache forums as well. Let's hope somebody can provide some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I'd say that you are dealing with a certificate trust issue.

Without seeing how you are setting up the connection specifically I can say with no certainty though.

The "peer not authenticated" means that somewhere along the line the verification of the certificates as presented by one or more of the servers cannot be verified.

**EDIT**
Since the proxy is under your control you have a load of flexibility at this time.

Please see [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580479/apache-httpclient-able-to-communicate-over-https-when-direct-but-not-via-proxy-e), it may suit your needs.

Comment: Yes, i have a unsecured proxy running via tcpmon, so no real security check needed there. If i remove the proxy piece, the call goes through successfully.

Comment: Had checked that earlier post, but couldn't find a difference between my code and the one mentioned in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580479/apache-httpclient-able-to-communicate-over-https-when-direct-but-not-via-proxy-e)

Comment: Ok with the edits you posted - if you are proxying https-over-http I don't see how tcpmon is going to be able to determine the content of the request.  You've gotten the target host as localhost/5555/http - you're going to be sending encrypted data through that. Uneless you've configured tcpmon's proxy to terminate and resign the SSL connection it will have no way of looking at the content.

Comment: Can you clarify which TCPmon you are using? The Apache page indicates that it is no longer supported or under active development. An alternative I found might be Membrane http://www.membrane-soa.org/soap-monitor/ which looks to have SSL support.

Comment: I am using one of the older version's (1.0) by Apache [TcpMon](http://ws.apache.org/tcpmon/). I am aware it's no longer in active development or support. But this older version works ok to just have a basic non secure proxy running. I don't need this proxy to do any kind of security check, etc. Does this proxy still needs to determine my request content, my understanding was it will just pass it over to the end target server which is https.

Comment: I'm unclear on the proxy operation with regard to proxying HTTPS-over-HTTP - I am not sure if that is a valid use case. The SSL portion is not so much a security check as it is a transport guarantee.

Comment: Basically this proxy will act more like router, not doing anything with the request. Even the sample examples for [proxy](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientExecuteProxy.java) on Apache http client show this usecase of end target being "https" while the proxy being "http". I am not sure how are those cases working.